# Use Environment.Tickcount to determine how long a computer has been on

Tags: sql, vb.net, wmi

I have been working a on a project in which i need a rough idea of how long a computer has been on.

To this end i have this code.

`TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount).ToString("dd:hh:mm:ss:ff")` Can someone verify this is good?

What datatype is needed in sql for the above format? 
Thanks

Comment: `Environment.TickCount` is a 32-bit signed Integer, and will therefore only give you an uptime to 24.9 days.  I'm sure someone can suggest a better method.

Comment: Related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373253/gettickcount-differs-from-task-managers-and-cmd-uptime-span-why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a rough idea of how long a computer has been on:`

Windows reports that value various ways: as `GetTickCount64` from `kernel32`, it is a `PerformanceCounter` and it is in `WMI`.  It only reports system up time since the last reboot.  If the last reboot was a week ago, it may only report 5 days if a net of 2 days was spent sleeping, so it is approximate.

This makes sense since the system cannot be said to be "up" when sleeping/hibernating/stand by.  TaskManager Performance tab:

[image]

```vb
Friend Shared Function GetWMIItem(wmiclass As String, qItem As String) As String
    Dim retVal As String = ""
    Dim query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", qItem, wmiclass)

    Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        For Each item As ManagementObject In searcher.Get

            Dim p = item.Properties(qItem)
            If (p IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (p.Value IsNot Nothing) Then
                retVal = p.Value.ToString
                ' should be nothing else
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
    End Using
    Return retVal
End Function
```

To use it:

```
Dim uptime = WMI.GetWMIItem("Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System",
               "SystemUpTime")
Dim tsUp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(uptime))
```

The return is seconds, not milliseconds. If you need the last boot time:

```
Dim lastBootStrVal = WMI.GetWMIItem("Win32_OperatingSystem", "LastBootUpTime")
```

To read it, there is a special converter since it is in a special format:

```
dtLastBoot = Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(LastBootTimeString)
```

---

There is less code using `PerformanceCounter` (see link in the comment), but it is just as slow:

```
Using uptime As New PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")
    ' need to call NextValue once before using a PerformanceCounter
    uptime.NextValue
    ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(uptime.NextValue))
End Using
```

Otherwise they are all the same, `GetTickCount64()` offers better resolution, but it is still approximate depending on the amount of time sleeping.